# Error in accessing the Cloudfoundry Local App URL

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I need some help with a locally deployed app in the Local pivotal Cloud Foundry VM.

Recently, I have installed the pivotal cloud foundry in a Windows Server 2012 VM and had deployed the Spring-music app in the local. Now I want to share this url with others, but when I give the URL generated in the APP PUSH Commands to others they are not able to see that app. Can you help how to share a APP url to others so that they can view the app.

http://spring-music.local.pcfdev.io/  -- this is the Local APP URL

I have tried few commands to create my own shared domain and route to it still facing issue in accessing the app from other systems.

```
cf create-shared-domain tcp.example.com --router-group default-tcp

cf push spring-music –d tcp.example.com --random-route

cf create-route s1 tcp.example.com --random-port

cf map-route myapp tcp.example.com --random-port
```

after trying all these also i am not able to access the app with url generated.
can anyone help me with generating a URL for externals system to access my APP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

PCF Dev is a development only, local instance of PCF.

If you want to expose a local application you will have to register a DNS name that points to your machine, open firewall ports and then create your newly registered domain in your PCF instance.

Answer (score -1):

You have installed Pivotal Cloud Foundry in local machine which means it is PCFDev. However you can't share APP Url outside from your machine. Because APP is running in within your machine.

If your perspective is sharing APP URL than using PCF in local machine then you can switch to [Pivotal Web Services(PWS)](https://account.run.pivotal.io/z/uaa/sign-up) which is hosted by Pivotal Cloud Foundry on AWS Cloud. It is available for free trial with 87 credits.