# Creating API endpoint for local machine in cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am very new to cloud foundry.

I started working on pushing sample apps to local API endpoint. api.local.pcfdev.io.
Now is there way to create ur own local API endpoint, where you can connect to your own local machine and push the apps. because if I disconnect from the internet I am not able to access the app.

So can you explain how to create your own API endpoint for pushing the apps into the local instance of the cloud foundry.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "your own API endpoint"?

Answer (score 0):

PCF by default creates an endpoint for your deployed app.

You can add a new new route to an app.

You can create your own domain and assign that to your app. However you may run into issues accessing this url on PCF dev as it requires more work. See this link - [Error in accessing the Cloudfoundry Local App URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369875/error-in-accessing-the-cloudfoundry-local-app-url)

Please go thru the documentation - https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html